# Clojure transients - assoc! causing exception

Tags: list, clojure, shuffle

Here is the function I'm trying to run...

```
(defn mongean [cards times]
  (let [_cards (transient cards)]
    (loop [i 0 c (get cards i) _count (count cards) _current (/ _count 2)]
      (assoc! _cards _current c)
      (if ((rem i 2) = 0)
        (def _newcur (- _current (inc i)))
        (def _newcur (+ _current (inc i))))
      (if (<= i _count)
        (recur (inc i) (get cards i) _count _newcur )))
    (persistent! _cards)))
```

It's resulting in this Exception...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentHashSet$TransientHashSet cannot be cast to clojure.lang.ITransientAssociative
```

Being new to clojure, I'd also appreciate any constructive criticism of my approach above.  The goal is to take a List, and return a re-ordered list.

Comment: What do you mean by re-ordered list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to implement the [Mongean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Mongean_shuffle) shuffle. Your approach is very imperative and you should try to use a more functional approach.

This would be a possible implementation, were we calculate the final order of the cards (as per Wikipedia formula) and then we use the built-in `replace` function to do the mapping:

```
 (defn mongean [cards]
   (let [num-cards (count cards)
         final-order (concat (reverse (range 1 num-cards 2)) (range 0 num-cards 2))]
      (replace cards final-order)))

  user> (mongean [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8])
  (8 6 4 2 1 3 5 7)
```

Comment: really clever... clojure continually makes me feel like an idiot... Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "Your approach is very imperative", also are there any "golden" resources for those of use not use to the functional style, coming from a OO classical background?  Thanks again.

Comment: When I started playing with Clojure I missed a lot the classic imperative `for` loop. How can you do anything without it? :). One of the pillars of functional programming is about not using mutating state. If you use `transient` you are immediately saying "I need mutable state!". `transient` should be reserved for sections of code were you really need a performance boost. About what resources, I have read just the Clojure books, but search SO as there are several questions about how to learn func programming

Answer (score 2):

How do you call that function? It looks like you're passing a set, so that its transient version will also be a set and hence can't be used with any of the `assoc` functions, as they work on associative data structures and vectors:

```
user=> (assoc #{} :a 1)
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentHashSet cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Associative  clojure.lang.RT.assoc (RT.java:691)

user=> (assoc! (transient #{}) :a 1)
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentHashSet$TransientHashSet cannot be cast to clojure.lang.ITransientAssociative  clojure.core/assoc! (core.clj:2959)

; the following works as it uses maps and vectors
user=> (assoc {} :a 1)
{:a 1}
user=> (assoc! (transient {}) :a 1)
#<TransientArrayMap clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap$TransientArrayMap@65cd1dff>
user=> (assoc [] 0 :a)
[:a]
```

Now, let's try to discuss the code itself. It's a bit hard to follow your code and try to understand what the goal really is without some more hints on what you want to achieve, but as general comments:

- you have a `times` input parameter you don't use at all
- you are supposed to use the result of a transient mutation, not assume that the transient will mutate in place
- avoid transients if you can, they're only meant as a performance optimization
- the binding `_current (/ _count 2)` is probably not what you want, as `(/ 5 2)` really returns `5/2` and it seems that you want to use it as a position in the result
- constants like `_count` don't need to be part of the `loop` binding, you can use the outer `let` so that you don't have to pass them at each and every iteration
- use `let` instead of `def` for naming things inside a function
- `(if ((rem 1 2) = 0))` is definitely not what you want

Now, leaving aside the shuffling algorithm, if you need to rearrange a sequence you might just produce a sequence of new positions, `map` them with the original cards to produce pairs of `[position card]` and finally `reduce` them by placing the card at the new position, using the original sequence as the seed:

```
(defn generate [coll] ; counts down from (count coll) to 0, change to
                      ; implement your shuffling algorithm
  (range (dec (count coll)) -1 -1))

(defn mongean [cards times]
  (let [positions (generate cards) ; get the new positions
        assemble (fn [dest [pos card]] ; assoc the card at the wanted position
                   (assoc dest pos card))]
    (reduce assemble cards (map vector positions cards))))
```

If you simply want to shuffle:

```
(defn mongean [cards times] (shuffle cards))
```